# create circle in react native by percentage?

Tags: css, react-native

I have a view with 50% width, its' parent having the whole width of the phone, i want to make it circle though, this is my code that does not work:

```
  clockContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width:Dimensions.get('window').width
  },
  clock: {
    width: '50%',
    borderRadius: '100%', // divide this by 2?
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
```

i looked around and it says you divide its' width by 2, but i don't know how to implement it in this case. Help?

Comment: my thought is the you have to set height for it, am i wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native only allows for *numeric* inputs in its CSS values, not percentages.

You'll want to calculate the `borderRadius` the same way that you calculate the parent `width`, and then simply divide by two:

```
borderRadius: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2
```

Or:

```
borderRadius: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.5
```

Comment: hello, i am just introducing myself in react native and having this 1st project, thank you! never thought that way